# reusable rust vector with associated vector of slices

Tags: rust

I need rust code to read lines of a file, and break them into an array of slices. The working code is

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut f = stdin.lock();
    let mut line : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    loop {
       line.clear();
       let sz = f.read_until(b'\n', &mut line).unwrap();
       if sz == 0 {break};
       let body : Vec<&[u8]> = line.split(|ch| *ch == b'\t').collect();
       DoStuff(body);
    }
}
```

However, that code is slower than I'd like. The code I want to write is

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut f = stdin.lock();
    let mut line : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut body: Vec<&[u8]> = Vec::new();

    loop {
       line.clear();
       let sz = f.read_until(b'\n', &mut line).unwrap();
       if sz == 0 {break};
       body.extend(&mut line.split(|ch| *ch == b'\t'));
       DoStuff(body);
       body.clear();
    }
}
```

but that runs afoul of the borrow checker.

In general, I'd like a class containing a Vec<u8> and an associated Vec<&[u8]>, which is the basis of a lot of C++ code I'm trying to replace.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

I realize that I could replace the slices with pairs of integers, but that seems clumsy.

No, I can't just use the items from the iterator as they come through -- I need random access to the individual column values. In the simplified case where I do use the iterator directly, I get a 3X speedup, which is why I suspect a significant speedup by replacing collect with extend.

Other comments on this code is also welcome.

Comment: Can you include the signature for `DoStuff`? It looks like it currently takes ownership of a `Vec<&[u8]>`. And is that signature open for changes? Transferring ownership is antithetical to reusing allocations.

Comment: A signature like `&[&[u8]]` wouldn't take ownership of the vec.

Comment: I don't think that would solve the problem with the second example. If you extend body by borrowing into line then body's type is now Vec<&'line [u8]>, but line is mutated with `line.clear()`. How much slower than the cpp implementation are we talking @Andy? Do you have an upper bound for the number of splits of a line? Does `Vec::with_capacity()` help? After trying that, I might measure the performance of `body.extend(line.split(|ch| *ch == b'\t').map(|v| v as *const [u8]));` and see if it really makes much of a difference

Comment: Sorry that i was sloppy with DoStuff(). It should have just been a comment that some use goes there. DoStuff() is not the issue; the problem is with extend.

Comment: I don't understand how I would use with_capacity -- collect creates the Vec.
The C++ is about 2.5X faster, although it's doing a little bit more stuff.
When I replace my extend call with your extend(map) call, it tells me
the trait `std::iter::Extend<*const [u8]>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<&[u8]>

Comment: @AndyJewell are you using the `--release` build for your timings?

Comment: @flumpb yeah, you're right, modifying `line` while `body` (even when empty) is bound to it kinda ruins my idea.

Comment: @kmdreko -- yes, I'm using --release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems like the answer is

1. No, it's not possible to reuse the vector of slices.
2. The way to go is to make something like a slice, but with integer offsets rather than pointers. Code is attached, comments welcome.
3. Performance is currently 15% better than the C++, but the C++ is part of a larger system, and is probably doing some additional stuff.

````
/// pointers into a vector, simulating a slice without the ownership issues
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct FakeSlice {
    begin: u32,
    end: u32,
}

/// A line of a text file, broken into columns.
/// Access to the `lines` and `parts` is allowed, but should seldom be necessary
/// `line` does not include the trailing newline
/// An empty line contains one empty column
///```
/// use std::io::BufRead;
/// let mut data = b"one\ttwo\tthree\n";
/// let mut dp = &data[..];
/// let mut line = cdx::TextLine::new();
/// let eof = line.read(&mut dp).unwrap();
/// assert_eq!(eof, false);
/// assert_eq!(line.strlen(), 13);
/// line.split(b'\t');
/// assert_eq!(line.len(), 3);
/// assert_eq!(line.get(1), b"two");
///```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TextLine {
    pub line: Vec<u8>,
    pub parts: Vec<FakeSlice>,
}

impl TextLine {
    /// make a new TextLine
    pub fn new() -> TextLine {
        TextLine {
            line: Vec::new(),
            parts: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.parts.clear();
        self.line.clear();
    }
    /// How many column in the line
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.parts.len()
    }
    /// How many bytes in the line
    pub fn strlen(&self) -> usize {
        self.line.len()
    }
    /// should always be false, but required by clippy
    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.parts.is_empty()
    }
    /// Get one column. Return an empty column if index is too big.
    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> &[u8] {
        if index >= self.parts.len() {
            &self.line[0..0]
        } else {
            &self.line[self.parts[index].begin as usize..self.parts[index].end as usize]
        }
    }
    /// Read a new line from a file, should generally be followed by `split`
    pub fn read<T: std::io::BufRead>(&mut self, f: &mut T) -> std::io::Result<bool> {
        self.clear();
        let sz = f.read_until(b'\n', &mut self.line)?;
        if sz == 0 {
            Ok(true)
        } else {
            if self.line.last() == Some(&b'\n') {
                self.line.pop();
            }
            Ok(false)
        }
    }
    /// split the line into columns
    /// hypothetically you could split on one delimiter, do some work, then split on a different delimiter.
    pub fn split(&mut self, delim: u8) {
        self.parts.clear();
        let mut begin: u32 = 0;
        let mut end: u32 = 0;
        #[allow(clippy::explicit_counter_loop)] // I need the counter to be u32
        for ch in self.line.iter() {
            if *ch == delim {
                self.parts.push(FakeSlice { begin, end });
                begin = end + 1;
            }
            end += 1;
        }
        self.parts.push(FakeSlice { begin, end });
    }
}
````

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of completeness, and since you are coming from C++, a more Rusty way of writing the code would be

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn do_stuff(body: &[&str]) {}

fn main() {
    for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let body = line.split('\t').collect::<Vec<_>>();
        do_stuff(&body);
    }
}
```

This uses [`.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) from `BufRead` to get an iterator over `\n`-delimited lines from the input. It assumes that your input is actually valid UTF8, which in your code was not a requirement. If it is not UTF8, use `.split(b'\n')`, `.split(b'\t')` and `&[&u8]` instead.

Notice that this does allocate and subsequently free a new `Vec` via `.collect()` every time the loop executes. We are somewhat relying on the allocator's free-list to make this cheap. But it is correct in all cases.

---

The reason your second example does not compile (after fixing the `DoStuff(&body)` is this:

```
12 |        line.clear();
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |        body.extend(&mut line.split(|ch| *ch == b'\t'));
   |        ----             ---- immutable borrow occurs here
   |        |
   |        immutable borrow later used here
```

The problem here is the loop: Line 12 `line.clear()` will execute *after* line 15 `body.extend()` from the second iteration onwards. But the compiler has figured out that `body` borrows from `line` (it contains references to the fields inside `line`). The call to `line.clear()` mutably borrows `line` - all of `line` - and as far as the compiler is concerned is free to do anything it wants with the data it holds. This is an error because `line.clear()` could possibly mutate data that `body` has borrowed immutably. The compiler does not reason about the fact that `.clear()` obviously does not mutate the borrowed data, quite the opposite in fact, but the compiler's reasoning stops at the function signature.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response.
I cannot assume that the input file is utf8
Vec<u8> does not have split(u8) but only the predicate version
I understood why the second one was failing, I included it to suggest the shape of something that would avoid the extra allocations, which do indeed seem to take a lot of time.